# Overriding the keypress event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, accessibility

I am trying to make my application accessible, and in doing so, one of the requirements suggests that the whole application should be usable via keyboard. To complete this I have added keypress to the following code

```
    $("#id").unbind("click keypress").bind("click keypress", function () {/*some code*/});
```

Now this does work, but the problem is that it works for every other key as well. I would only want it for **Enter** and **SpaceBar**. I could use a keydown catching the keycode and responding to it only if its 13(Enter) or 32(Space), but I have stupidly made the keypress change in over 70 places and only found it now while testing. Is there a way in which I can override the default jQuery keypress event so that it would only respond to the pressing of the above 2 keys??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
  $("#id").unbind("click keypress").bind("click keypress", function (e) {
if(e.which == 13 || e.which == 32){
/*some code*/
}

});
```

Please Update me if it works for you

Comment: Actually I was hoping for a solution which I can use globally at one place rather update it individually in all 70 places.

Comment: Well then you can put a common class or something common in those 70 places and then use it instead of #id selector. That ll be better. I GUESS

Comment: Also, the click event doesn't seem to work anymore. Nevertheless, thanks for the prompt reply.